# Andorid Jetpack Compose State not Updating

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-mvvm

I am working on a Jet Shopping App using Room DB with reference from HOODLAB youtube video & my full code is build without error.

Problems:

1. When I am adding an item to the list, it is not showing.
2. When I am adding a store, it is not displaying in the dropdown menu.

Github link - https://github.com/its-ks/Shopping_List_app.git

See the screenshot below:

[image]

This is the code I use:

```
Row {
            TextField(
                value = state.store ,
                onValueChange = {
                    if(isNewEnabled) onStoreChange.invoke(it)
                },
            modifier = modifier.weight(1f),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            shape = Shapes.large,
            label = {Text(text = "Store")},
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.KeyboardArrowDown, contentDescription = null,
                modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.clickable {
                    onDialogDismissed.invoke(!state.isScreenDialogDismissed)
                })
            })
            if(!state.isScreenDialogDismissed){
                Popup(
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        onDialogDismissed.invoke(!state.isScreenDialogDismissed)
                    }
                ){
                    Surface(modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                        Column {
                            state.storeList.forEach{
                                Text(text = it.storeName,
                                modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
                                    .padding(8.dp)
                                    .clickable {
                                        onStoreChange.invoke(it.storeName)
                                        onDialogDismissed(!state.isScreenDialogDismissed)
                                    },
                                )
                            }
                            
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            TextButton(onClick = {
                isNewEnabled = if (isNewEnabled) {
                    onSaveStore.invoke()
                    !isNewEnabled
                } else {
                    !isNewEnabled
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = if (isNewEnabled) "Save" else "New")
            }


        }
```

Comment: Where you are adding name in the list , provide full code

Comment: are you updating room-db and expecting your ui to update automatically. If so my friend. You need to either use, (LIveData or Flow) to observe your changes in your ui. You can't expect for them to work automatically

Comment: Yes @AkashSinha

Comment: @ParthLotia I am doing it manually

Comment: Your data source i.e. roomdb needs to send data in any observable form. Your UI will not update just by updating roomdb. You need to observe the changes in state and accordingly update the ui

Comment: Yes @AkashSinha is right, you need to use livedata or flow in order to update the UI . First it will goes into the observer than list will get update data.

Comment: https://github.com/its-ks/Shopping_List_app.git                                                                                     Guys please help me through my project code please , I have provided Github link to u guys please help @AkashSinha

Comment: ok let me check.

Comment: yes please @AkashSinha